# Tracking progress of playing Instream FAN Video Ad

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, exoplayer, facebook-audience-network

I have encountered a problem while implementing Instream FAN Video Ads handling.

What I need is to track a progress of playing each ad.
As [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android-instream/) say, all we need to do to play video ads is to provide view layer which ads player will be added to. It seems to be no way to handle playing these ads by your own (by obtaining url to direct ad video and putting it into your own player - as it is in playing IMA ads).

Unfortunately, standard FAN SDK enables us to handle only following events: 
onError, onAdLoaded, onAdVideoComplete, onAdClicked, onLoggingImpression.
Moreover, there is no direct access to underlying player and there is no way to enforce FAN SDK to use your own player instead.

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me with this problem.